# Puppet Enterprise 3.3 on RHEL 7 - Error: Could not find terminus console for indirection node

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, rhel7

With a fresh install (monolithic) of PE (Puppet Enterprise) 3.3 on RHEL (Redhat Enterprise Linux) 7 I'm currently getting the following error:

```
...
Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/git_html_path.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/lib/facter/git_version.rb
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed when searching for node puppet.***: Could not find terminus console for indirection node
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

when running on the master node:

```
puppet agent --test
```

The console.rb file exists on the disk: `/opt/puppet/share/puppet/modules/puppet_enterprise/lib/puppet/indirector/node/console.rb`

Version: `3.6.2 (Puppet Enterprise 3.3.0)`

Not that Puppet appears to be even getting as far as contacting the console, but I can access it through a web browser and the first 4 test runs appeared in the console, but now they don't (nothing has changed). I can't work out why the console terminus cannot be found, or even where Puppet is looking (apparently in the wrong place)

Ruby version: `ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-linux]`